# asp.net MVC - code first foreign key lets me input anything

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm quite new to MVC and had searched and checked multiple solutions, but none worked for me yet.

I have a database made using Code First. It has 3 tables: Club, Match and Round. In every round there's a few matches. In every match play 2 clubs. Match contains one foreign key to Round (which works great) and two separate multiple keys to Match (home and away team).

When I add MatchesController with views using EF and start the application and try to input new match, I have a dropdownlist of Rounds from database - works amazing. I'd like to have two dropdownlists with team names/IDs from database as well so I can select teams playing, but for some reason I have two textboxes that let me write anything, as if the FK constraints don't exist.

I'm having quite a problem with it as I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - is it the foreign keys? I coded them like that while browsing other questions, but maybe I messed up?

Round class:

```
public class Round : IValidatableObject
{

    public int RoundID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RoundNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
}
```

Club class:

```
    public class Club
{
    public int ClubID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ClubName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Match> HomePlays { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Match> AwayPlays { get; set; }
}
```

Match class and its DB context class:

```
    public class Match
{

    public int MatchId { get; set; }

    public int HomeClubId { get; set; }
    public int AwayClubID { get; set; }

    public virtual Club HomeClub { get; set; }
    public virtual Club AwayClub { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int RoundId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoundId")]
    [InverseProperty("Matches")]
    public virtual Round Round { get; set; }

}

public class Context : DbContext
{

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
 .HasRequired(m => m.HomeClub)
 .WithMany(m => m.HomePlays)
 .HasForeignKey(m => m.HomeClubId)
 .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Match>()
             .HasRequired(m => m.AwayClub)
             .WithMany(m => m.AwayPlays)
             .HasForeignKey(m => m.AwayClubID)
             .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

And then there's the generated MatchesController with actions Index and Create:

```
    public class MatchesController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Matches
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var match = db.Match.Include(m => m.Round);
        return View(match.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Matches/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.RoundId = new SelectList(db.Round, "RoundID", "RoundID");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Matches/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MatchId,HomeClubId,AwayClubID,Club1Goals,Club2Goals,RoundId")] Match match)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Match.Add(match);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.RoundId = new SelectList(db.Round, "RoundID", "RoundID", match.RoundId);
        return View(match);
    }
}
```

And the Create view:

```
@model ProjSty3Exp.Models.Match

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Match</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HomeClubId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeClubId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeClubId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AwayClubID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AwayClubID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AwayClubID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoundId, "RoundId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("RoundId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoundId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Get action method

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.RoundId = new SelectList(db.Round, "RoundID", "RoundID");
        ViewBag.AwayClubID = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "ClubID", "ClubID");
        ViewBag.HomeClubId = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "ClubID", "ClubID");
        return View();
    }
```

In razor view

Replace

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeClubId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

By

```
@Html.DropDownList("HomeClubId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Replace

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AwayClubID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

By

```
@Html.DropDownList("AwayClubID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Post action method

```
    // POST: Matches/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MatchId,HomeClubId,AwayClubID,Club1Goals,Club2Goals,RoundId")] Match match)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Match.Add(match);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.RoundId = new SelectList(db.Round, "RoundID", "RoundID", match.RoundId);
    ViewBag.AwayClubID = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "ClubID", "ClubID", match.AwayCludId);
    ViewBag.HomeClubId = new SelectList(db.Clubs, "ClubID", "ClubID", match.HomeClubId);
    return View(match);
}
```